# Try to figure it out how to translate a long ternary operator with more than one condition into long if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary

I found online this snippet and I'm trying to figure it out how to translate it in a plan if statement:

```
return a.price > b.price ? 1 : a.price === b.price ? a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1 : -1;
```

In my opinion, if I had written an if statement:

```
if (a.price > b.price) {
    return 1;
} else if (a.price === b.price) {
    return 1;
} else if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return -1;
}
```

But I'm not quite sure what it means a question mark and right after another question mark, same problem with a colon. I get that, the colon, in this case, could be an else if statement (in that order), but what about the question mark? any hint?

Comment: Are you trying to translate an `if` statement into a `ternary` operator or a `ternary` operator into an `if` statement?

Comment: it looks like a funny return result for a sorting function. does it sort right?

Comment: a long ternary into long if statement, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping it like this will help

`a.price > b.price ? 1 : (a.price === b.price ? (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1) : -1)`

```
a.price > b.price ? 1 : x
x = a.price === b.price ? y : -1;
y =  a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
```

The translated IF ELSE would be

```
if(a.price > b.price){
    return 1
} else {
    if(a.price === b.price){
        if(a.name > b.name){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is right, but the next isn't. This:

```
a.price === b.price ? a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1 : -1;
```

separated out, looks like:

```
a.price === b.price
  ? (
    a.name > b.name
      ? 1
      : -1
    )
  : -1;
```

The inner conditional is `a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1`.

If the prices are not equal, `-1` is returned. Otherwise, the names are compared. To translate this correctly:

```
if (a.price > b.price) {
  return 1;
}
if (a.price !== b.price) {
  return -1;
}
if (a.name > b.name) {
  return 1;
}
return -1;
```

If this is being used for a `.sort` callback, another option which is equivalent to the above is:

```
return a.price - b.price || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
```